# delphi xe5 64-bit not working

Tags: delphi, 64-bit, delphi-xe5

This is peculiar. My Delphi XE5 was working properly and based on build switch would generate the EXE and put it in the appropriate folder (Win64\Debug or Win64\Release).  Something unknown broke this functionality.  If I create a new app, add 64-bit target, then compile, it creates a Win32 folder but no Win64 folder.  It puts the EXE in the Win32\Debug folder (and there is no Win64 folder.

[image: Error message when trying to run "64-bit" app]

So I manually created the Win64 and Win64\Debug folders.  I now try to run and get this error message (and there is no exe that gets deployed in Win64\Debug):
[image: error message when trying to run with folders manually created]

I'm at wits end on this one and things I have done:

1. verified run Delphi as administrator
2. killed Acronis (seems like someone ran into something similar)
3. Project options output folder is set to .\$(Platform)\$(Config)

Comment: You should not run as admin

Comment: You also should not save user files in the root of your boot drive.  You have a documents folder - I suggest you try using it.

Comment: Better yet, don't save anything on your boot drive at all ;=)

Comment: Why not run as admin?  Any reference to why that's not preferable?

Comment: why the down vote with no explanation?

Comment: If you run as admin, you'll not discover standard user bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - pilot error on my part, though have no idea how this happened.  There was an environment variable set with a "user-override" that was set to Win32. I sure don't ever recall setting that nor know why I would. Deleting that override cured the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that your anti virus software is interfering. Try disabling it to prove the point. If that is the problem, exclude your output directories from checking.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the output folders in your Project Options are what they should be.  Sounds like maybe the paths got altered.